# Adding attributes to Shopify's {% form %} liquid tag

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid

Is it possible to add attributes to Shopify's `{% form %}` liquid tag? I want to give all my forms id's so that I don't have to rely on parent elements to target their styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can add attributes.

Example:

```
{% form 'contact', id: "test" %}
```